# Download progress bar not working, Python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, download

I'm trying to make a GUI where the user clicks a button and the app downloads a file from the internet. I want to have a progress bar showing how long until the file download is complete. To achieve this I have implemented a thread to run the progress bar's function when the download button is clicked. Here is the code I'm using:

```
def progthread():
    threading.Thread(target=download).start()

def download():
    blocknum = 0
    blocksize = 0
    url = "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png"
    filename = "C:\My Python Apps\MyFile.png"
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=10000):
            f.write(data)
            percent = int(blocknum * blocksize / int(total_length))

            progress['value'] = percent
```

When I run the application, it downloads the file and no errors come up. But the progress bar does not do anything. I tried using `progress.update()` and `progress.update_idletask()` but the progress bar was still not working.

How can I get the progressbar to show the download progress of the file?

Comment: You've not assigned values to blocknum and blocksize within the loop, so they're always stuck at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the loop you have blocks tkinter's mainloop, so the whole GUI locks up. For something like this you should launch the download loop in a separate thread so that it can run at the same time as the tkinter mainloop. You can use a tkinter IntVar to update the progress bar from the other thread.

If you update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then I can help you implement that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it more minimal than that though. The other version of this code that I tried and works uses the `urllib` package but I know a lot of websites trigger 403 errors when this is used, so the example I provided in the question is what I have adapted to not use `urllib`. But how would I put the download loop in a separate thread?

Comment: Okay I figured out how to do threading and updated my question, but the problem persists. I honestly do not know how to make my example more minimal than that though, but I'm just thinking now, I think it may be a problem with getting the block size when downloading, because in my `urllib` code it gets that value and returns it, however I cannot implement it the same way while using the `requests` package.

Comment: I don't want you to only make it minimal, but make is complete and verifiable as well. Read the link. This is common when asking for help online. Make a complete program that I can run, including imports, so that I can show you where the problem is. Sure I could do this myself; but I've got better things to do than write boilerplate code.

Comment: I kinda got it working but it's giving me a whole different issue which I will  post in a separate question today. But your suggestion of using a thread did help and at least got the progress bar to at least do something :)